# How many days until the planets are again at their closest distance?

Tags: trigonometry

I came across this problem in the recent Mathematics Teacher magazine:

> Planet A and Planet B have circular orbits around their sun, with radii of $1.5 \times 10^8$ and $2.25 \times 10^8$ kilometers, and orbital periods of $350$ and $643$ days, respectively. Consider a time when both planets are at their closest distance to each other. How many days until they are again at their closest distance?

I attempted it algebraically, but kept going in circles.  Then I went to Desmos, played around with the trig functions: $\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi t}{350}\right)$ and $\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi t}{643}\right)$ and saw they intersected at about $t = 768$, which ends up being the number of days until they are in the desired alignment.   How do we solve this algebraically?

The algebra I initially tried was to find the distance between the two planets $A$ and $B$ needs to be $\dfrac34$ which is the difference between $2.25$ and $1.5$.  [The basis of my algebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzYnJ.png) I then used the Pythagorean Theorem: $(y_A - y_B)^2 + (x_A - x_B)^2 = 0.75^2$

$x_a = 1.5\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi t}{350}\right), y_a = 1.5\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi t}{350}\right)$

$x_b = 2.25\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi t}{643}\right), y_b = 2.25\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi t}{643}\right)$

where $t$ is days. After working through it I end up with $\dfrac{2\pi t}{643} = \dfrac{2\pi t}{350}$ which only gives $t = 0$.

I also graphed the functions for each $x$ and $y$ and saw they crossed on at the desired value of about $768$.

I know I am missing something. But I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Hint: the planets are at their shortest distance apart when their angles are the same. So the assumption says that $2\pi t/350$ and $2\pi t/643$ differ by a multiple of $2\pi$ (at $t=0$ say), and you are trying to find the next value of $t$ where that is true. This should yield a simple linear equation for $t$, whose solution will be $1/(\frac1{350}-\frac1{643}) \approx 768$.

Comment: Ah I see.  Instead of 2πt/350 = 2πt/643, the equation should have been 2πt/350 = 2πt/643 + 2π which is trivial and left to the reader as an exercise.  Thanks, Greg!